# Backbone.js click event doesn't work with touch

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

```
events: 
    'click' : 'select'
```

When using this event on Mobile Safari the event gets triggered twice when touched. Is this a known bug or something that I am causing on my own?

I've since changed it to

```
events: 
    'touchstart' : 'select'
```

and it works great but means that it will not work in normal browsers anymore.

Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 16):

Try this code:

```
TouchView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: function() {
    return MOBILE ? 
       {
         "touchstart": 'select'
       } : 
       {
         "mousedown": 'select'
       }
  }
}
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/dira/Ke2px/2/

Comment: Didn't work for me (didn't see anything output in console). The backbone event system was working though because the event triggered when I changed it to "click #main".

Comment: @Nippysaurus you will need to have your own code to detect `MOBILE`.

Answer (score 3):

I have used Modernizr to detect the touch device and used following code and this worked for me.

```
events :function(){ 
   return Modernizr.touch ? 
     {
         "touchstart #edit" : "openEdit",
     }: 
     {
         "click #edit" : "openEdit",
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

I've solved the same issue generically by creating [backbone.touch for Backbone](https://github.com/nervetattoo/backbone.touch) that will monkey patch Backbone.View to respond to touch events when a touch device is used, or regular click events when not.

You can either just include the source file to have it transform all of your `click` events in Backbone.Views, or you can take a peek at the code and implement it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I defined both events types and it works for me on a mobile and desktop:

```
events: {
'click' : 'select',
'touchstart' : 'select'
}
```

Comment: That will fire the 'select' method twice, since when you tap on a touch device it fires all the events: touchstart
touchmove
touchend
mouseover
mousemove
mousedown
mouseup
click

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Backbone, but maybe try setting it conditionally?

```
if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) {
  // 'touchstart': 'select'
} else {
  // 'click': 'select'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just include the jquery touchpunch library and that's it.

https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch

Answer (score 0):

Using coffeescript, I'd do the following, I don't ever find a reason to bring in modernizer when every mobile device these days is really a touch device, I mean when was the last time you had to really support something that didn't?

```
window.isTouchDevice =  (/android|webos|iphone|ipod|ipad|blackberry|iemobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()) )

  events: ->
    for k, v of this when /click/.test(k) and isTouchDevice
      mobileKey = k.replace('click','touchstart')
      events[ mobileKey ] = v
      delete events[ k ]
    return events
```

Coffeescript reads better for these type of list comprehensions imho.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me.

```
events:{
  'click #edit':'select',
  'touchstart #edit':'select'
},
select: function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('open upload dialog ', e.type);
}
```

now when you test this if  the device is touch e.type should be touchstart and only fire once.
Same for click on no-touch device.
In case anybody is still looking for a simple solution for this.