# How to implement touch events in backbonejs?

Tags: backbone.js, hammer.js

I need to implement touch based events in backbonejs View. I tried with hammer jquery special events but it didn't work for me.

Comment: What about using "Backbone.View.extend()" :)

Comment: I am using Backbone.View.extend()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try extending the events with the check mobile deveice and add specific events like

```
events: function() {
    return MOBILE ? 
       {
         "touchstart": 'select'
       } : 
       {
         "mousedown": 'select'
       }
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dira/Ke2px/2/

As we can see from the question [Backbone.js click event doesn't work with touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828054/backbone-js-click-event-doesnt-work-with-touch)

Comment: This is working well in modern browsers but i need a fallback for IE 7+

Comment: Ohh.. k ..jsut check that MOBILE boolean is comming proper in iE .. ??

Comment: else "var isTouch = 'ontouchstart' in window" try this ..

Answer (score 0):

use it as a jquery plugin and then normally use the events property to set it up and listen for these events on desired elements

```
events: {
    'tap': 'onTap',
    'hold .dragging-handle': 'onHold'
    // etc...
},

onTap: function(e) {
    // do whatever with the event data 
}
```