# Firing event click works on Browser but not on IOS app

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js, cordova

I'm currently developing an app with Backbone.js, underscore.js and jQuery Mobile. It's a "quiz" with several questions, and when users tap the answer, it goes to next question.

It works kindly fine on browser, but I want to develop an IOS app using Phonegap, and (after some little changes) everything seems to go ok, but when I click some answer, the event (neither click, nor tap) don't fire. I tried it with a "submit" button, and it worked, so there's something strange there :(

Relevant code:

```
var quizView = Backbone.View.extend({
    collection: new quizCollection(),
    render: function() {
         (...)
    },
    events: {
        'click .resp': 'saveStatus', // original
        'tap .resp': 'saveStatus',  // and maybe...?
        'touch .resp': 'saveStatus'// what if...?
    },
    saveStatus: function(event) {
        var el = $(event.currentTarget).siblings("input");
        var score = (el.val() == questions.selected.correcta) ? (1) : (0);
        datosPartida.preguntasResp++;
        datosPartida.score += score;
        this.collection.showQuestion();
    }
});
```

Where "`.resp`" is the class in the label of radio input.

The code of the template is:

```
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Pregunta</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="content">
    <div>
        <%
            var id = preguntas.id;
            var corr = preguntas.correcta;
            var it = 0;
        %>

        <h3><%= preguntas.pregunta %></h3>
        <% _.each(preguntas.respuestas, function(respuesta) { %>
            <input id="respuesta_<%= it %>" name="respuesta_<%= id %>" type="radio" value="<%= respuesta.id %>">
            <label data-role="button" class="resp" for="respuesta_<%= it %>">
                <%= respuesta.respuesta %>
            </label>
                <% it++; %>
        <% }); %>
           <!-- <button data-role="button" class="sigpreg">Siguiente</button> -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Why is my tap/click not firing the event on IOS, but it does on browser?

I hope some help, thanks in advance.

---

Finally i found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828054/backbone-js-click-event-doesnt-work-with-touch).

Set the event `touchstart` and it works fine :)

Comment: have you tried `vclick`?

Comment: Yes, I already tried _vclick_ but neither work :(

Comment: ok try this, `.ui-radio` instead of `.resp`.

Comment: Just tried with `.ui-radio` but doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: try `[data-role=button].resp`

Comment: Nope, doesn't work with `[data-role=button]` with or without the class, unfortunately :(

Comment: try `change` instead of `click`.

Comment: Finally I got it! I tried changing `touch` to `touchstart` and it works! Thanks for your time, Omar