# Handling touch events in a Backbone View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, touch-event

I want my backbone app to behave nicely on mobile devices.  Does it makes sense to replace 'click' events with 'touchend' events?

```
var CoolView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : $("#coolEl"),
    events: {
        'touchend' : 'clickHandler'
    }
});
```

add it to the events object?

```
var CoolView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : $("#coolEl"),
    events: {
        'click' : 'clickHandler',
        'touchend' : 'clickHandler'
    }
});
```

something else?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oakley349/ate0Lpos/8/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Backbone.touch](https://github.com/nervetattoo/backbone.touch) plugin which will replace the click events to touch events if the device is mobile.

Comment: I saw this plugin and I will probably go with it.  Curious if there were other solutions out there.  Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7828579/1742747

Which is to detect

```
navigator.userAgent.match(/mobile/i)
```

and make a determination about which listener to apply based on that.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dira/Ke2px/2/